# Position alert next to input field with same space between multiple input fields

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

On my form I have two fields like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("State", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="tt-container">
            @Html.Editor("StateName", new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "StateName", @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateId, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-warning col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <h4>Warning!</h4>
        <p>Please select the state the appears as you continue to type in the state where you are from.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

On the view it looks like so:

[image]

How do I make it so that there is the same space between the State input field and the email input field, just like the amount of space between city and state input fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bootstrap grid examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/)

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
}
.alert{
min-width:250px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row container">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email address:</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
         <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
     </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
     </form>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 container">
       <div  class="alert alert-info">alert</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please re-read my question.  I believe the title of my question was unclear.  I have edited that.  I know how to put an alert next to an input field.

Comment: Your edited answer will only put the alert next to the input field that is at the top of the form.. not input fields that are in the middle of the form

Comment: I did this by adding a CSS. Hope to be useful